# Power On/Off API in Samsung Tizen TV

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

Is it possible to programmatically to turn the TV On/Off via the Web (or other) APIs from within Tizen?  (Can't find any reference to this in docs)

Comment: Any update @Boris?

Comment: We didn't find a way to do this unfortunately

Comment: I am also getting only native way to do this, did not find any way through web application

Comment: @Boris did you find any way how to turn off the screen on TV? Does the "native" way work?

Answer (score 3):

Up until **Tizen 4.0** it was possible to use these (*now deprecated*) Power API calls:

```
tizen.power.turnScreenOn();
tizen.power.turnScreenOff();
```

These has now changed to:

```
//Turn on
tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL");

//Turn off
tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_OFF");
```

**NOTE:** That `SCREEN_OFF` cannot be requested directly and has to be called in a event handler.

You can read more about managing power resources [here](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.tutorials/html/web/tizen/system/power_tutorial_w.htm).

Comment: Appears like this is only for wearable devices and not enabled for TV/Monitors

Comment: @Boris Take a look at [this](https://docs.tizen.org/iot/api/5.0/tizen-iot-headed/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__DEVICE__POWER__MODULE.html)

Comment: @Sanguinary so it means that this can be called only from C apps and not from web apps? Do you know the reason why it is like that? Is there some kind of JS wrapper around the C api? Thanks